# AsyncTask returns null value in main thread

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Calling a variable which was meant to be defined via an `AsyncTask` in a user input event always returns null. I call the `AsyncTask()` in my main thread as shown below:

MainActivity.java:

```
ContactDataRepository contactDataRepository = new ContactDataRepository(mContext);

String name = contactDataRepository.getContactNameByPhoneNumber(
                phoneNumber, null, null, null, null);
```

ContactDataRepository.java:

```
public String getContactNameByPhoneNumber(
            String phoneNumber,
            TextView tvName,
            TextView tvNumber,
            TextView tvAvatar,
            ImageView ivDisplayInitials)
            throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        return fetchName(phoneNumber, tvName, tvNumber, tvAvatar, ivDisplayInitials);
    }


private String fetchName(
            String phoneNumber,
            TextView tvName,
            TextView tvNumber,
            TextView tvAvatar,
            ImageView ivDisplayInitials)
            throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>() {
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {

                mPhoneNumber =
                        worksideDatabase.phoneNumberDao().getPhoneNumberByNumberQuery(phoneNumber);

                if (mPhoneNumber != null) {
                    contactName =
                            worksideDatabase
                                    .contactDao()
                                    .getFullNameByContactId(mPhoneNumber.getContactId());
                }

                return contactName;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);

                // Hack method to transfer the title name to the message
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences =
                        PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
                final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

                if (mPhoneNumber != null) {
                    if (tvName != null) tvName.setText(contactName);
                    if (tvAvatar != null) tvAvatar.setText(getInitials(contactName));
                    if (tvNumber != null) tvNumber.setText(phoneNumber);
                    if (ivDisplayInitials != null) ivDisplayInitials.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    editor.putString("ToolbarTitle", contactName);
                } else {
                    if (tvName != null) tvName.setText(phoneNumber);
                    editor.putString("ToolbarTitle", phoneNumber);
                }
                editor.apply();
            }
        }.execute().get();

        return contactName;
    }
```

Can I amend the existing code, such that the `name` string in MainActivity is properly defined, or will I have to rewrite the AsyncTask?

Comment: maybe its because AsyncTask runs in the background and your method returns `contactName` immediately, even before AsyncTask assigns it any value?

Comment: @ashu Do I have to cast `.execute().get()` to assign it the required value? Is there any other way (i.e. by not passing the view to be updated to the AsyncTask)?

Comment: `return contactName;` That will not return a name. The asynctask is just started. It takes a time before doInBackground will be started. When doInBackground finishes onPostExecute will be called. But not if you use .get().

Comment: from the looks of it, you want synchronous execution. with the way that you want it to happen, I am wondering why would you bother using AsyncTask. Just use synchronous logic. Otherwise, you'll have to pass the view to the AsyncTask. Or implement some way to wait for the async task to complete which is same as a synchronous call. This is more about thread synchronization than the Android Framework.

Comment: @ashu The issue is that I am accessing data within a database, and I am not allowed to run queries on the main thread synchronously. Hence why I am using an AsyncTask. I understand that what should be done here defeats the purpose of using an AsyncTask.

Comment: If the query needs to happen asynchronously, then you will have to pass your view to the async task and update it in `onPostExecute` callback. That's the standard way. Alternatively, if you do not want to use async task, you can use a Java Thread in conjunction with `View#post`, which can be another thread to schedule a callback on the main thread.